# "Haber de" y futuridad

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

La [entrada de "haber"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber) en lo "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas" incluye este trozo:

> a) **haber de + infinitivo**. En el español general, esta perífrasis
>   denota obligación, conveniencia o necesidad de que el sujeto realice
>   la acción expresada por el verbo —o, si el infinitivo es pasivo, de
>   que le suceda lo expresado por el verbo— y equivale a tener que,
>   fórmula preferida en el habla corriente:
>
> > «*He de reconocer que al principio me incomodó la idea de encontrármelo durante la travesía*» (Padilla Imposibilidad [Méx. 1994]);
> >
> > «*Hubimos de esperar varios meses hasta conseguir recursos económicos*» (Laín Descargo [Esp. 1976]);
> >
> > «*La imagen de la Virgen hubo de ser retirada*» (Hora [Guat.] 14.7.97).
>
> A veces expresa, simplemente, acción futura:
>
> > «¡No he de morir hasta enmendarlo!» (Cuzzani Cortés [Arg. 1988]);
> >
> > «Ni siquiera la guerra habría de aliviar el temor y el respeto que imponía aquel valle a trasmano» (Benet Saúl [Esp. 1980]).
>
> Tampoco en el caso de esta perífrasis es admisible en la lengua culta el uso de la forma habemos
>   para la primera persona del plural del presente de indicativo:
>
> > «Ahora los perdedores habemos de ahogar las penas en el vino y pensar en
> >     otras cosas» (RdgzMéndez Bodas [Esp. 1976]);
>
> debió decirse hemos de ahogar las penas.

Para los propósitos de esta cuestión, consideremos solamente la acepción de futuridad. Me gustaría haceros dos preguntas:

- ¿Con qué frecuencia es "haber de" usado con esta acepción?
- ¿Cuáles son los matices semánticos de esta futuridad?

Soy un hablante nativo de portugués y la forma perifrásica "haver de" es muy corriente, principalmente en la expresión oral. También en el portugués, es raro ver en textos modernos "haver de" expresar primariamente necesidad (como "tener que"). Antes comporta una idea de porvenir, especialmente con una componente de deseo, promesa (generalmente vaga), órdenes (poco vigorosas, pues que apuntan para un futuro incierto), vaticinio, confianza o (en lo imperfecto) arrepentimiento o lamento (en "havia de ter visitado a exposição enquanto esteve aberta", el significado de "havia" es semejante a "debía"). ¿Cuánto (si algo) de esta caracterización es aplicable?

Por favor, apuntad los errores que encontraréis en esta pregunta.

Comment: Como hablante español, reconozco y entiendo la acepción que indica futuro de **haber de + infinitivo**, aunque diría que se restringe a ámbitos literarios. Personalmente no la escucho nunca en el habla coloquial. Creo que también son aplicables los matices que dices de deseo, promesa, órdenes poco vigorosas, etc., excepto, quizás, las de arrepentimiento y lamento (en ese caso se usa «debía haber visitado» o «tenía que haber visitado»).

Comment: @Chewie Quizá arrepentimiento/lamento (o deseo frustrado) no sea la mejor caracterización. En "havia de ter visitado" o "havia de haver visitado", "havia" transmite deseo o obligación; es lo infinitivo compuesto (ter/haver + participio pasado) qué sitúa el objeto del deseo en lo pasado. En cambio, "havia de visitar" exprime o un deseo (pero de una forma más débil que "hei de") o algo objetivamente deseable (pero que no quiero/puedo hacer). Sin embargo, el contexto puede indicar que la acción no es ya posible: "foi lindo, havias de ver!" (=havias de ter visto).

Comment: @Chewie Otros valores de lo imperfecto "haver + de": los mismos que el presente (en el estilo indirecto); condicional ("ainda havia de casar (=casaria) antes de falecer").

Comment: Coincidiendo con Chewie, "he de llevar el coche al mecánico" no es muy utilizado en Latinoamérica. Sí es posible escuchar "voy a llevar el auto al mecánico", "llevaré el auto ...", "tengo que llevar el auto ..."

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de futuridad, es muy poco utilizada en el lenguaje oral. Suena bastante literario. En el resto de usos es más común en lenguaje oral, aunque no deja de ser algo formal.