# "Haber" vs "A ver"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Tengo una pregunta que aun mis amigos que hablan español como nativos no saben con seguridad.

Es común decir "A ver," por ejemplo, hoy me dijo una amiga:

> A ver si la ves.

Creo es una forma de [A + infinitivo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3301/12) que quiere decir:

> Vas a ver si la ves.

Pero después, mi amiga se corrigió hasta:

> Haber si la ves.

Y eso me parece muy raro.  Y ella no está segura de cual forma es correcto.

Parece a mi que usar "haber" en una situación así solo es correcto si es una certeza como en [esa pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3135/12):

> Haber de verla...

Ya mi pregunta:  Hay alguna situación donde es correcto decir:

> Haber si ... ?

O en otra forma, hay alguna situación donde los dos "haber" y "a ver" parecen, o pueden ser correctos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes encontrar todos sus usos en el apartado consultas de la RAE

http://www.rae.es/consultas/ver-haber

Suenan igual pero deben distinguirse adecuadamente en la escritura

*A ver*, antes de un condicional se especifica:

> Delante de una oración introducida por la conjunción si, expresa, bien expectación, curiosidad o interés, a veces en forma de reto; bien temor o sospecha; bien deseo o mandato:
>
> - ¡A ver si adivinas lo que estoy pensando!
> - A ver si te caes.
> - A ver si eres más organizado de ahora en adelante.

Mientras que *haber* (verbo) se usa como auxiliar del participio o del impersonal y como conjunto de bienes cuando es sustantivo.

*Haber de* cuando se trata de una obligación, como se describe en el enlace que pones.