# ¿Cómo explicar de forma sencilla la diferencia entre "a ver" y "haber"?

Tags: verbos, ortografía, educación

Aunque ya tenemos en el sitio una pregunta sobre ["Haber" vs "A ver"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8382/12637), en esa pregunta la diferencia se explica de forma académica, usando tecnicismos que pueden importarle poco al ciudadano medio. El caso es que la diferencia entre estas dos expresiones es nula en el habla, y por tanto es muy fácil confundirlas, y muchas veces me encuentro cuando intento explicar la diferencia que el mensaje no llega, tal vez debido a que o bien uso tecnicismos (como pasa con la *Ortografía* de la RAE) o a que no encuentro buenos ejemplos.

Así pues, ¿cuál podría ser un ejemplo sencillo, o una explicación que use términos muy sencillos, que explique la diferencia entre "haber" y "a ver", y que alguien que no sienta el más mínimo interés por los entresijos de la lengua pueda entender para conocer dicha diferencia?

La idea sería dar una regla sencilla, o algún ejemplo muy sencillo. Se me ocurre como ejemplo el caso de "aparte" y "a parte", para el que yo siempre explico que si se puede poner "una" (o "ninguna") entre "a" y "parte", se escribe separado, si no se escribe junto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En general:

- Si lo puedes cambiar por "existir", es "**haber**".
- Si no, es "**a ver**".

> *{A ver ~ Haber}* si nos vemos -> <strike>*Existir*</strike> si nos vemos -> *{***A ver** *~ <strike>Haber</strike>}* si nos vemos.
>
> Tiene que *{a ver ~ haber}* un motivo -> Tiene que *existir* un motivo -> Tiene que _{<strike>a ver</strike> ~ ***haber***}_ un motivo.

El resto de "opciones": *aver*, *haver*... son incorrectas siempre.

<sub>PD: Si eres medievalista y estás explicando un texto del s. XIII, *podría* ser "ha ver", pero lo normal es que no.</sub>

Comment: Solo se me ocurre que no funcionaría cambiarlo por existir cuando *haber* se usa como auxiliar, aunque en ese caso es mas difícil confundirlo con *a ver*

Comment: @blonfu normalmente la confusión suele ser escribir "haber" cuando es "a ver", en sentido contrario no suele pasar, por lo que la regla de walen sigue siendo válida en la mayoría de los casos en los que hay confusión.

Comment: @walen también podría ser *haver*, *hauer*, *auer*, etc.  Vamos, había poca regla entonces ;-)

Comment: Recomiendo que se quite el PD.  El medievalismo no tiene lugar en esta discusión (pero podría caber si se planteara otra pregunta más amplia).

Answer (score 3):

Por dar otra alternativa: los casos en los que se suele generar la confusión son aquellos en los que la palabra va al principio de frase. En estos casos se puede aplicar una sencilla norma: se escribe "a ver" salvo cuando va seguido de un participio:

> **A ver** si lo logramos entre todos. <sub>(No hay participio.)</sub>
>   **Haber** venido antes. <sub>(Hay participio.)</sub>

En el resto de los casos en los que pueda haber confusión, se puede aplicar [la regla de @walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22358/12637) (como en esta misma frase: "haber" equivale a "existir"). Hay casos en los que no aplicaría, como en "¿debería haber llegado ya?", que son cuando el verbo "haber" actúa como auxiliar y no como verbo principal. En este caso se aplicaría el mismo razonamiento del participio mencionado anteriormente. También se puede observar que si es "a ver" suele ir precedido del verbo "ir" (o se puede añadir previamente el verbo "ir" si no lo lleva) o alguno equivalente:

> **A ver** si nos vemos = **Vamos a ver** si nos vemos.
>   Ayer **fueron a ver** una película.
>   Mi hermano **se pasó a ver** a la abuela. <sub>(En este caso "pasarse" equivale a "ir".)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre el ejemplo cuando explico las diferencias entre `"hay, ahí y ay".`

En este caso si la persona no tiene mucho interés como dices le diría:

### A ver:

> Sería cuando me decís: -*¡Qué lindo esto!* o *¿Ya viste esa chica?.*
>
> Entonces te respondería: *-A ver muéstrame...*

### Haber:

> Sería cuando me preguntás: -*¿Habrá pan en casa?.*
>
> y yo respondo: *-Supongo que ha de haber.*

---

**Entonces le daría una conclusión por ejemplo:**

> Entonces **a ver** es de *"ver con la vista"* y **Haber** es de si *"hay o no algo"*.